# Running rails project on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I a little bit new for heroku and postgresql and dont know how works translting from mysql to postgresql.
My application was developed on mysql and to run it from heroku i made some steps:
1. Added a `gem 'pg'` and `gem 'rails_12factor'` like that:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

And bundle it without production
2. I also changed my database.yml into:
(Also i have question, how can i use mysql in devolepment and postgre in production?)

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5
```

**But!**
When i tryed to work via heroku(downloading works fine) my dynamic pages wasnt working, and i get this errors:
[image: Errors]

So, i guessed that DB just doesnt migrate, OK, i runned via console this:
`heroku run rake db:migrate --app name`
Aaand i now i have this error:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "schoolings" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "students" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_e33c769d03"
FOREIGN KEY ("schooling_id")
REFERENCES "schoolings" ("id")
```

My questions:

**1. Why it happens? Did i miss some steps when deployed my app?**

**2. How can i separate production and dev DB in deployment.yml?**

Thanks, for any help!

Comment: make sure you have all your migrations as files.. to check that use `bin/rake db:migrate:status` I think there's one not ok.

Comment: I should check it on heroku or in app?

Comment: Ok, i tried this both on heroku ( it just doesnt know the command) and also on project : `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in 
resolve_symbol_connection': 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["default"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)` So i guess error is in my `database.yml`, but i totally dont know what shoud i write there

Comment: You need to provide Heroku the proper database credentials in the database.yml file for production.

Comment: @mahatmanich And how i can do this? The syntax of .yml files is new for me.

Comment: Your rails application should have a database.yml file in the config folder

Comment: But it already is in there

Answer (score 3):

First you have to create the database on heroku.

```
heroku run rake db:create --app-name
```

Then you can run the migrations.

Comment: I tried, and get this: `FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.`